# How to reorganize django settings file?

Tags: python, django

I have this standard django generated settings:

```
project/project
        |   __init__.py
        |   settings.py
        |   urls.py
        |   wsgi.py
```

And it's working. However,  I want to reorganize this layout to this:

```
project/project/settings
                |   __init__.py
                |   base.py
        |   __init__.py
        |   urls.py
        |   wsgi.py
```

When I do it of course it's not working:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

So where and what I need to change in order this to work?

Comment: Have you changed anything in your settings file? What is the code inside your __init__.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, just edit `manage.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
```

to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.base")
```

and also `wsgi.py`

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.base")
```

Comment: why do we also need to change wsgi.py?

Comment: you need to do it in production

Answer (score 0):

Well according to your error which says, you have no SECRET_KEY defined. You need to add one to your settings.py.
Django will refuse to start if SECRET_KEY is not set. You can read more about it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY)

The SECRET_KEY can be anything...but if you want to use Django to generate one, you can do the following from the python shell:

```
>>> from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
>>> chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
>>> SECRET_KEY = get_random_string(50, chars)
>>> print SECRET_KEY
```

Copy the secret_key to your setting file.

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you moved your old `settings.py` into `settings/base.py`, I assume you want to split your Django settings into multiple files.
So, the only thing you have to do is to ensure all your settings are available at module level. In `settings/__init__.py`, write something like

```
from .base import *
from .another_setting_file import *
# etc.
```

Then, all your settings variables (`settings.SECRET_KEY`, `settings.DEBUG`, etc) will be available to the rest of the Django app, without need to modify default `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value.

Bonus: using this method, you can override a setting defined in `base.py` in another file as soon as you import `base` first in `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

`Django` is looking into `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable by default. It's set to 
`'{your_project_name}.settings'` module or package (again, by default). So you can modify that to be `'{your_project_name}.settings.base'` to read settings from `base.py` module.

But you can also accomplish that without modifying environment variables. With your folder structure `Django` is looking into `settings` package you've created. So, you just need to import all the settings defined in `base.py` there. Just place this code into `settings/__init__.py` module:

```
from .base import *
```

This allows you to import settings from different modules and perform some more complex logic like checking the environment variables and importing settings based on your current environment. For example importing settings by checking in which environment the app is running:

```
import logging
import os


# Default is local environment
environment = os.getenv('MACHINE_ENV', 'local')

if environment:
    if environment.lower() == 'local':
        from .local import *
    elif environment.lower() == 'staging':
        from .staging import *
    elif environment.lower() == 'prod':
        from .prod import *
```